# hibernate one-to-many child updating

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I have a parant entity Project and child entity Task(onetomany relationship). I would like to know how update child right. All examples I found are with one table.Thanks

Comment: Check out this link:-https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-how-to-delete-child-entities/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you need here? if you want to update the child of current parent then iterate through the child list / set and then modify the appropriate child within that for each loop. You could also update your parent too. so here when you flush / commit your transactions your parent table and the child tables as well get updated successfully.